# Get log file from NLog configuration instead of hardcoding

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nlog

I have a `.NET Core` application which has `NLog` configured. This is the contents of the `NLog.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="false" internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogToConsole="true" internalLogIncludeTimestamp="true" keepVariablesOnReload="true">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>
    <variable name="appId" value="" />
    <variable name="componentId" value="" />
    <variable name="file-target-path" value="" />
    <variable name="file-target-name" value="" />
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Console" name="console-target" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}Z ${uppercase:${level}} APP=${var:appId} COMP=${var:componentId} [${when:when='${threadname}'=='':inner=${threadid}:else=${threadname}}] ${message} - Logger=${logger},Level=${uppercase:${level}},ThreadId=${threadid},${onexception:,Exception\=&quot;${exception:format=tostring}&quot;}" />
        <target xsi:type="File" name="file-target"
                layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}Z ${uppercase:${level}} APP=${var:appId} COMP=${var:componentId} [${when:when='${threadname}'=='':inner=${threadid}:else=${threadname}}] ${message} - Logger=${logger},Level=${uppercase:${level}},ThreadId=${threadid},${onexception:,Exception\=&quot;${exception:format=tostring}&quot;}"
                fileName="${basedir}/${var:file-target-path}/${var:file-target-name}.log"
                archiveFileName="${basedir}/${var:file-target-path}/${var:file-target-name}.{###}.txt"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
                archiveAboveSize="5242880"
                archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
                maxArchiveDays="31" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="console-target" />
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="file-target" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm now writing a class which parses the log for a the Regex value `\sApplication Running\s([\-]+?)\s`. I currently have the log file path hard coded in my `StreamReader` like below:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\sApplication Running\s([\-]+?)\s");

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\path\to\my\log_file.log"))
            {
                ...
            }
```

How can I update this so the log file is obtained from the logging configuration instead of the hard coding it in my class?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the regex? Please explain the example with more details

Comment: Reworded my question slightly. I'm not so much worried about the regex as I am the hard coding of my log file location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve log file location from **LogManager.Configuration**.

```
var nlogFileTarget = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<FileTarget>().First();
var dummyEventInfo = new LogEventInfo { TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow };
var logFilePath = nlogFileTarget.FileName.Render(dummyEventInfo);
```

Comment: Good one, I think that by using `LogManager.Configuration.FindTarget` and  
`LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent`, this answer is the best now possible.

Comment: That's getting there but using that gives me `fileName "C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\src\\My.Application\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\/./Logs/My.Application.log" string` as the `logFilePath` value and I need it to be something like `C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\src\\My.Application\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\Logs\\My.Application.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution:

```
<nlog>
    <variable name="file-target-path" value="" />
    <variable name="file-target-name" value="" />
    <variable name="file-target-filename" value="${basedir}/${var:file-target-path}/${var:file-target-name}.log"" />

    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="file-target" fileName="${file-target-filename}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="file-target" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And then you can do this:

```
var filetargetPath = NLog.LogManager.Configuration?.Variables["file-target-filename"]?.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
```